# Modifying header in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, http-headers, content-type

I was wondering how to modify the `headers` `content-type` to `text/xml` in `ruby on rails`. I want to do this because an android app i'm developing retrieves data by parsing xml from a remote link. The server retrieves the data and outputs it as xml. So I just need to change the content-type so the app can parse the data properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render):

> By default, Rails will serve the results of a rendering operation with
>   the MIME content-type of text/html (or application/json if you use the
>   :json option, or application/xml for the :xml option.). There are
>   times when you might like to change this, and you can do so by setting
>   the :content_type option:
>
> render :file => filename, :content_type => 'application/rss'

Comment: Will this work in rails 2.3.x? My hosting provider only supports this version of rails right now which sucks but I got to live with it.

Comment: yes it's the same: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/layouts_and_rendering.html